# VB.Net HttpWebRequest.GetResponse always timeout

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm always getting time out with this code.

the post is https and works fine, but never get a response,

I try with HttpWebRequest and WebRequest, with more timeout, but no response

can you help me?

```
>System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = New TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
>
>req = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)

>req.Method = "POST"

>req.Timeout = 60000
>
>Dim byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(URL)
>
>req.ContentType = "text/xml"
>
>req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
>
>Dim dataStream As Stream

>dataStream = req.GetRequestStream()
>
>dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
>
>dataStream.Close()

>dataStream.Dispose()
>
>Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
>
><b>response = req.GetResponse() '---->>> always timeout here </b>
>
>dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
>
>Dim reader As StreamReader

>reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
>
>Dim responseFromServer As String

>responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

>reader.Close()

>dataStream.Close()

>dataStream.Dispose()

>response.Close()
```

Comment: Ensure that your URL is correct and can actually be requested

Comment: hi, yes the URL is correct, the post works, but not the response